# Calculating the line-to-neutral voltage of a generator

Tags: generator, three-phase, power-engineering, power-grid, line

> A three-phase generator is connected to a strong grid with
> line-to-line voltage 14 kV and frequency 50 Hz. The generator is rated
> at 15 kV and 180 kVA. The resistance in the windings is 2 Ohm/phase
> and the reactance is j3 Ohm/phase. The current in one phase was
> measured to be: I= 1500 / -25º A.
>
> What is the line-to-neutral voltage of the generator, |Ei|=____ kV.

Hi, I've got issues understanding what I should calculate and what "Ei" actually means?

I tried to calculate the I(phase)*Z(polar) to get the Ei(line-to-neutral), which gave me 5408,32V. Which is wrong.
Then I tried to take the V(line-to-line)/sqrt(3) to get Ei, which gave me 8082V which is also wrong.
How am I supposed to do it?

Comment: Show how you calculated those values and also explain what the correct answer is.

Comment: @Andyaka, I did explain how I calculated? I took the phase current multiplied with the impedance's polar form, which should give me the phase voltage. This was, however, incorrect. Then I attempted to take the line to line voltage divided with sqrt(3) to get the line to neutral voltage, which was also wrong. I can't give you the correct answer because I don't know what it is.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's homework without an attempt at a solution

Comment: @VoltageSpike I've attempted to solve it twice, with two different approaches?! I have written every step of both processes.

Comment: @gripen saying "I've tried this" isn't the same as showing your work.  What if you applied it wrong or missed a step?  Am I reading your current correctly to be 1500A at 25 degrees lag?  That seems impossibly high if the generator is putting out ~14kV and is only rated at 180kVA.